# Why do rain clouds form in the first place?

Tags: everyday-life, atmospheric-science, evaporation, weather, condensation

**Thought process leading to the question**

It's cold over here in India and I noticed that while breathing out some cloudy thing comes out of my mouth (I found it is called **EBC** (Exhaled Breathe Condensate)).
[image: A EBCing girl]

I concluded that the reason must be something like:

- the water vapour comes out of our nose (or mouth) and gets condensed on the dust particle in the air around me and form cloud like thing (since the temperature is not less than $4°C$ I conclude that that must be the case).

(Is this conclusion true?)

The interesting thing is that it soon diffuses into the atmosphere around it. But...! Guess what? Clouds don't. So I thought since nothing can stop this diffusion process then the clouds must be in equilibrium with their surrounding air. So I started thinking about the formation of clouds and here it goes:

- Suppose that initially there is a clear sky over a water body and it's a hot sunny day. So the water molecules at the surface of water vaporizer into the air and the go on an upward journey where they in due process cool down and start condensing on the dust particles around them (acting as the nucleation point).

**Question**

But here are some questions related to it:

- Why doesn't vapour diffuse around into the air (like the case I have stated)?
- Why do only some points act as favourable site of condensation and not others i.e., to say why doesn't the cloud spears out covering all of the water body?

---

Please do point out if any of my conclusions gets wrong anywhere.

Comment: BTW, clouds are a lot more dynamic than they may appear to be at a distance. Look closely at the edges of a cloud, sometime (preferably with binoculars).

Comment: Breathing out in cold air leads to a different https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point, which also rapidly changes when the air is mixed with surrounding air. This mixing process also happens in clouds, but on a different time scale and with other processes like updrafts influencing the dew point.